# Wix - how to set mime type under <iis:WebSite>

Tags: iis, wix

I am facing issue in Wix 3.10 installer. I want to set MIME Type of .dxview on IIS; I know we can do it if we add MIME type under iis:WebVirtualDir, but in my case there is no Virtual directory, and I want to achieve this under iis:website when my website is installed, but it's not adding mime type.

Below is the XML.

```
 <iis:WebSite Id="AppWebsite" Description='My App' Directory='INSTALLDIR' AutoStart='yes' StartOnInstall='yes'>
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="2053" />
      <iis:WebApplication Id="AppApplication" Name="[AppWebsite][WEBSITE_ID]" WebAppPool="AppPool"></iis:WebApplication>
       <!-- configure mime types -->
      <iis:MimeMap Id="MIME_DXVIEW" Extension=".dxview" Type="txt/html" />
    </iis:WebSite>
```

Comment: I would start from analysing the installation log file. It's quite hard to tell what could go wrong here. The snippet looks just fine to me.

Comment: Hell yan, actually according to wix toolset documentation, need to write mimemap tag under website tag will work but it is not working but if we write mimemap tag under is:WebVirtualDir then its working

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".dxview" mimeType="text/html" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See this post: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18631

Comment: Hello GoTo, please check below image shared and desktop project do not have web.config file. Please check image on this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxuywrgjj46udpf/stack.png?dl=0

Comment: Your link is blocked by my proxy. If you don't have a web.config then just create one, no?